# c# to vb.net linq select

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have this bit of code:

```
Contacts = model.Contacts?.Select(Create).ToList() ?? new List<Contact>()
```

which is part of a model factory:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the Account entity from the view model
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The Account view model</param>
/// <returns>An Account entity</returns>
public static Account Create(AccountViewModel model)
{

    // If the model is null, return null
    if (model == null) return null;

    // Return our model
    return new Account
    {
        AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber,
        AvailableDeliveryDates = model.AvailableDeliveryDates,
        BusinessCategory = model.BusinessCategory,
        Category = Enumerations.GetDescription(model.Category),
        CountryCode = model.CountryCode,
        Name = model.Name,
        Disabled = model.Disabled ? "Y" : "N",
        OnStop = model.OnStop ? "Y" : "N",
        ProductCatalog = model.ProductCatalog,
        Profile = model.Profile,
        Trade = model.Trade ? "Y" : "N",
        ShortAccountNumber = model.ShortAccountNumber,
        StatementAccountNumber = model.StatementAccountNumber,
        SalesOfficeNotes = model.SalesOfficeNotes,
        TerritoryCode = model.TerritoryCode,
        Type = Enumerations.GetDescription(model.Type),
        UnmannedAddress = model.UnmannedAddress ? "Y" : "N",

        Address = Create(model.Address),
        Contact = Create(model.PrimaryContact),
        SalesAnalysisRepresentative = model.SalesAnalysisRepresentative,
        CommissionAnalysisRepresentative = model.CommissionAnalysisRepresentative,
        ServiceRepresentative = model.ServiceRepresentative,
        Currency = new Currency
        {
            Code = model.Currency.Code,
        },
        Finance = Create(model.Finance),
        Group = new Group
        {
            Description = model.GroupName
        },                

        Contacts = model.Contacts?.Select(Create).ToList() ?? new List<Contact>()
    };
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates the Contact entity from the view model
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The Contact view model</param>
/// <returns>A Contact entity</returns>
public static Contact Create(ContactViewModel model)
{

    // If the model is null, return null
    if (model == null) return null;

    // Return our model
    return new Contact
    {
        Email = model.Email,
        Fax = model.Fax,
        Name = $"{ model.FirstName } { model.LastName }",
        Telephone = model.Telephone
    };
}
```

When I put this into a converter, it threw an error due to the null check

```
model.Contacts?
```

So I removed it and made the line as this:

```
Contacts = model.Contacts.Select(Create).ToList()
```

without the null coalescing operator too.
The convert stated that the line should be written as this:

```
Contacts = model.Contacts.[Select](Create).ToList()
```

But it will not compile.
Does anyone know how I can get this to work.

PS:

```
Contact = model.Contacts.Select(Create).ToList()
```

is short for

```
Contact = model.Contacts.Select(m => this.Create(m)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Create` is a delegate, in VB.NET you use `AddressOf`

```
Contacts = model.Contacts.Select(AddressOf Create).ToList()
```

But you should also use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) in VB.NET:

```
Contacts = model.Contacts?.Select(AddressOf Create).ToList()
```

But the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) in VB.NET is `If`:

```
Contacts = If(model.Contacts?.Select(AddressOf Create).ToList(), New List(Of Contact)())
```

Comment: I wonder if there is _anything_ in VB.NET that is not horrible.

Comment: @UweKeim: well, look at the edited part, the  null-coalescing operator in VB.NET, _that_ is horrible ;-)

Comment: Using the Handles keyword on an event method declaration is kind of nice when you are making something quick and easy.

Comment: The only VB that should ever be written is VBA.